# series converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Determine whether the series
>   $$ \frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{4^3} + \cdots$$
>   converges or diverges.

Can I write this as $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^3}$ or is there another/better way of solving this?

Comment: It is the sum of two absolutely convergent series, yes. It equals $\frac{\pi^2+\zeta(3)}{8}$. What kind of "better way" are you looking for?

Comment: Compare it to $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You want $\sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty a_n$ with $0\leq a_n\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$. Since $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$ your sum also converges.

Comment: Why $ \frac{1}{n^2}$ ?

Comment: why not $ \frac{1}{n^3} $ ?

Comment: because then it would not be true that $a_n\leq \frac{1}{n^3}$

Comment: I'm sorry. $a_{n}$ is the whole series or 1 of the sums I wrote under the whole series?

Comment: it's the whole sequence

Comment: So, $a_{n} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{2n^3}$ ?

Comment: no, $a_n$ is just the $n$'th summand.